# Rails mountable engine and overriding another engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, overriding, rails-engines, actionview

I'm in the proces of converting my standard Rails app to an mountable engine. The app is comparable to a standard blogging app and i want every model, controller and view to be extendable hence my choice for a mountable engine.

One of the gems i use is Devise which is as far as i understand a sort of a mountable engine itself. It can be used inside a mountable engine as stated [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-devise-inside-a-mountable-engine).

I'm able to use it partially within my engine. Everything is working fine including some Devise controller i override like this one:

```
# config/routes.rb

Bbronline::Engine.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, class_name: "Bbronline::User", module: :devise,
    controllers: { registrations: "bbronline/devise_overrides/registrations"}
    ...

# controllers/bbronline/devise_overrides/registrations_controller.rb
require_dependency "bbronline/application_controller"

module Bbronline

class DeviseOverrides::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new_intermediair
    @user = User.new
  end
  ...
```

The correct view 'views/bbronline/devise_overrides/registrations/new_intermediair.html.haml' is also correctly loading as expected.

However my issue is that the views that i override without a custom controller are not properly loaded. For example the view that should the login view is located in `views/bbronline/devise/sessions/new.html.haml` and is not loaded. Instead the standard Devise login view gets loaded i.e. `devise-2.1.0/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb`

Of course i could solve this problem by overriding every controller with my own controller like i did with the registrations_controller above but this seems very ugly. Is overriding every controller the way to do this? Is there a more convenient way to override views from an mountable engine from within another mountable engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The view_paths are in incorrect order. Checking the view paths of Devise::SessionsController shows:

```
Devise::SessionsController.view_paths 
=> #<ActionView::PathSet:0x007fa1bf0e36f8 @paths= [/Users/harmdewit/Dropbox/Code/projects/brightin/bbr-online/bbr-online-gem/test/‌​dummy/app/views, 
/Users/harmdewit/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.‌​0/app/views, 
/Users/harmdewit/Dropbox/Code/projects/brightin/bbr-online/bbr-online-gem/app/vi‌​ews]>
```

The last path of the mountable engine should come before the middle devise path. The solution is setting the loading priority in application.rb like this:

```
#test/dummy/config/application.rb (the app that uses my mountable engine)
...
config.railties_order = [Blog::Engine, :main_app, :all]
...
```

This is also documented in the rails api: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html#label-Loading+priority

Thanks to José Valim for pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Any way I could make this change without having to change the configuration of my dummy application? I'd prefer to make this the default behavior whenever I load my gem.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to adjust the `config.railties_order` in every app that uses your engine, just `require 'devise'` on top of your **lib\my_engine\engine.rb** file.

Comment: While the other answers offer insight to exploring the view_paths, this is the answer if your engine is meant for loading and customizing other engines

Answer (score 1):

I need more information. Which controller are you defining and from which controller is it inheriting from? Which view is being rendered and which one did you expect to render? Also, `.view_paths` is your friend so try in your rails console the following:

```
Devise::SessionsController.view_paths
YourApp::SomeDeviseController.view_paths
```

This will give you a better idea of where each controller is searching for templates.

Comment: I'm not defining a controller, i just want to override the view. More specifically i want to override the view located in `devise-2.1.0/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb` without overriding the controller. Is this possible?

Comment: Oh .view_paths shows:


    Devise::SessionsController.view_paths
      => #<ActionView::PathSet:0x007fa1bf0e36f8
    @paths=
      [/Users/harmdewit/Dropbox/Code/projects/brightin/bbr-online/bbr-online-gem/test/dummy/app/views, /Users/harmdewit/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.0/app/views,
   /Users/harmdewit/Dropbox/Code/projects/brightin/bbr-online/bbr-online-gem/app/views]>


Bbronline::SessionsController does not exists of course, i do not override it

Comment: If you don't want to use a custom controller, just override the view, just place your new view at: `your-engine/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb` and make sure Devise's engine is loaded before your mountable engine (just require devise before). Again, calling `.view_paths` in your `Devise.parent_controller` or in your application controller will tell you the template lookup order.

Comment: Hrm, I can see that the devise view paths is coming *before* your engine one, that's why you can't override it. Try mangling with the load order or manually manipulating the `.view_paths` in your `Devise.parent_controller` or your application controller.